# Docusign Custom Button Routing

Tags: button, docusignapi

The DocuSign custom button does not route as per the order. See the button code below. The envelope goes directly to the second order and skipping the first one.

```
{!URLFOR('/apex/dsfs__DocuSign_CreateEnvelope', null, [ 
SourceID = HealthCloudGA__CandidatePatient__c.Id, 
CRL = 'Email~' + HealthCloudGA__CandidatePatient__c.OwnerEmail + 
';FirstName~' + HealthCloudGA__CandidatePatient__c.OwnerFirstName + 
';LastName~' + HealthCloudGA__CandidatePatient__c.OwnerLastName + 
';RoutingOrder~1;Role~Signer1'+ 
'Email~' + 
HealthCloudGA__CandidatePatient__c.Primary_Treating_Physician_Email__c + 
';FirstName~' + 
HealthCloudGA__CandidatePatient__c.Primary_Treating_Physician__c 
+';RoutingOrder~2;Role~Signer2',
DST = '5b651cdc-7553-4dd6-bd2b-7aad33aa84a4', 
LA = '0', 
LF = '0', 
OCO = 'Send' 
]  
)}
```

It should go to first person and once the first person sign the form then it should go to second person.

Comment: Can you please enable DS API logging by following [link here](https://support.docusign.com/en/guides/ndse-user-guide-api-request-logging), share that API logs after masking the document part.

Answer (score 0):

You are using a template (DST=) and your template overrides the definitions of the recipients. You should either not use a template, or change your template definitions to what you want.